# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Laravel on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, image, heroku, storage

I am trying to show pictures in Laravel project from storage that is linked in public.

but I am getting error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). It works in local, but it doesn't work on Heroku.

```
  <img class="card-img-top" src="{{asset('storage/'.$post->post_image)}}" alt="Card image cap">
```

Answer (score 1):

- Did you run the command php artisan storage:link?
- Try use storage_path('app/public/' . $post->post_image ).
- Read more: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem

Comment: I tried everything.. and on heroku is still the same error

Comment: 1. Run command: php artisan storage:link and post image to "storage/app/public" folder.
=> ``The [public/storage] directory has been linked.``
Now use: asset('storage/xxx').

2. If not run command, using storage_path().

Try it.